# Configure Odoo 13.0 with VS Code on Windows 10

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, odoo, odoo-12

I have been trying to configure Odoo 13.0 with VS Code on Windows 10 but couldn't make success.
I have searched for the solution on google and youtube but nothing was helpful.

I have installed all odoo extensions and python extension in vs code, but when i run an odoo python file it said

```
moduleNotFindError: No module named odoo
```

Then i open a folder where my odoo is installed,  now VS Code says

```
Odoo 13.0ythonpath: ython command not found
```

Please help me, please don't tell me to use pycharm

Answer (score 0):

The first message means that odoo is not installed in the Python environment you have selected (you can see it in the status bar after you have opened a Python file). The second one looks mis-formatted, but my guess is the odoo extension requires you configure the path to your Python interpreter in the odoo extension somehow. It seems you will have to resolve one of those two issues to run odoo (I assume it's something to run; I don't know what odoo is).